# numericals in word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the task of finding numeric in a word document and alternatively superscript and subscript them.

I used this:

```
test = True

Dim chr As Range
For Each chr In ActiveDocument.Range.Characters

If IsNumeric(chr.Text) And test = True Then chr.Font.Subscript = True
test = False
If IsNumeric(chr.Text) And test = False Then chr.Font.Superscript = True
test = True

Next chr
```

**This is only making all the numbers Superscript , not alternating between Super and Sub script**

example Text -
 " [17] Saied, M.H., Mostafa, M.Z., Abdel-Moneim, T.M., Yousef, H.A.: On Three Phase Six-
Switches Voltage Source Inverter: A 150° Conduction Mode. Member IEEE, Alexandria
Univercity (2006)"

now in tis example the macro would have to make 17 superscript and 150 subscript and 2006 as superscript..

Please someone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Range.Characters` to loop over the characters. Something like

```
Dim chr As Range
For Each chr In ActiveDocument.Range.Characters
    If IsNumeric(chr.Text) Then chr.Font.SubScript = True
Next chr
```

Then add some booleans that tell you if you have to set it to sub- or superscript

Comment: `test = True

Dim chr As Range
For Each chr In ActiveDocument.Range.Characters
    
    If IsNumeric(chr.Text) And test = True Then chr.Font.Subscript = True And test = False
    If IsNumeric(chr.Text) And test = False Then chr.Font.Superscript = True And test = True
    
  
   
    
Next chr`   I tried this way ... but it wont work ,, please help on this

Comment: `And` is a logical operator, not something to connect lines. Using `And` like this will cause VBA to evaluate both statements as booleans rather than setting the properties.

Comment: Could you please Construct this for me , I have tried but ,this might be way off for me

Comment: Just use a new line for each command. Again, `And` is a logical operator that can't be used to fit more than one command in a line but to compare boolean (logical) values. If you can't get it to work you will need to ask a new question or edit your answer because dealing with code in a comment is a bad idea.

Comment: Please don't replace my code with your non-working code (sorry said edit answer in my comment by accident). If you put something after `Then` (in the same line) the `If` block ends after that line. If you want to have more within the `If` block, continue at the next line and use `End If` at the end of the block.

Comment: Now the code in this question doesn't match the text, that's not better than the code in the new question not matching the text. You need to explain what the problem with the code is. I already described what your (current) problem is in my last comment, please read it.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone needs the answer to this .. here is what I did ,

```
  Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2000
  Dim vFindText As Variant
  Dim vReplText As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  vFindText = Array("\[", "\]  ", " \*")
  vReplText = Array("", "", "")
  With Selection
   With .Find
     .ClearFormatting
     .Replacement.ClearFormatting
     .Forward = True
     .Wrap = wdFindStop
     .MatchWholeWord = True
     .MatchSoundsLike = False
     .MatchAllWordForms = False
     .MatchWildcards = True
     .Format = True
     .MatchCase = True
     For i = 0 To UBound(vFindText)
         .Text = vFindText(i)
         .Replacement.Text = vReplText(i)
         .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
     Next i
     .Text = "[0-9]{1,}"
     .Replacement.Text = "^&"
     .Replacement.Font.Superscript = True
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, MatchWildcards:=True
 End With
 End With
 MsgBox "Numbers has finshed , calling double1"
 Call Numbers1
```

this will throw all numbers into subscript then it calls Sub Numbers1

```
Sub Numbers1()
Dim chr As Range
Dim firstChar As Word.Range
Dim test As Integer
test = 0
Dim firstAlphabet As Range

Selection.SetRange Start:=0, End:=100000

Set firstAlphabet = Selection.Range
For i = 2 To 1600
test = test + 2
Set firstChar = Selection.Characters(test)

If IsNumeric(firstChar.Text) Then firstChar.Font.Subscript = True

On Error Resume Next

Next i

End Sub
```

This will put all the numbers alternatively into subscript and superscript ....
**The code can be optimized obviously ,,, at present it takes too long to do the given job ,,, but after searching for a working method all day, this is the only thing that works**

hope this will help will Someone who comes finding this  :)